# Can't recreate just deleted node with UniqueNodeFactory

Tags: neo4j, node-neo4j

I just created a node with UniqueNodeFactory and his relationship with UniqueRelationshipFactory. I deleted the the node with the NeoEclipse and then I tried to recreate the same node and I get no exception and the node it's not recreated again. Anyone knows this is happening?

```
public Node getOrCreateNodeWithUniqueFactory(final Index<Node> nodeIndex, final String indexableKey,final String indexableValue) {
    UniqueFactory<Node> factory = new UniqueFactory.UniqueNodeFactory( Global.graphDB.getGraphDbService(), nodeIndex.getName())
    {
        @Override
        protected void initialize(Node created, Map<String, Object> properties) {
            created.setProperty(indexableKey, properties.get(indexableKey));
        }
    };

    return factory.getOrCreate( indexableKey, indexableValue );
}

    public Relationship getOrCreateRelationshipTypeWithUniqueFactory(Index<Relationship> index, String indexableKey, final String indexableValue, 
                    final RelationshipType type, final Node start, final Node end) {

    UniqueFactory<Relationship> factory = new UniqueFactory.UniqueRelationshipFactory(index) {
        @Override
        protected Relationship create(Map<String, Object> properties) {
            Relationship r =  start.createRelationshipTo(end, type);
            return r;
        }
    };

    return factory.getOrCreate(indexableKey, indexableValue);
}
```

Comment: could you post the full code that creates the node, as well as the code that check it hasn't been re-created at the end?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your issue. What I get is that there's a new node created the second time around. But it would help with the full source code. And also try with the method "getOrCreateWithOutcome" on UniqueNodeFactory to see whether it was created or not.